# Find, Replace, Remove - with in file

Tags: bash, replace, awk, find

I'm currently using this code:

```
awk 'BEGIN { s = \"{$CNEW}\" } /WORD_MATCH/ { $0 = s; n = 1 } 1; END { if(!n) print s }' filename > new_filename
```

To find a match on `WORD_MATCH` and then replace that line with `$CNEW`  in a file called `filename` the results are written to `new_filename`

This all works well. But I have an issue where I may want to DELETE the line instead of replace it.

So I set `$CNEW = ''` which works in that I get a blank line in the file, but not actually removing the line.

Is there anyway to adapt the AWK command to allow the removal of the line ?

The total aim is :

1. If there isn't a line in the file containing WORD_MATCH add one, based on $CNEW
2. If there is a line in the file containing WORD_MATCH update that line with the new value from $CNEW
3. If $CNEW ='' then delete the line contain WORD_MATCH.

There will only be one line in he file containing WORD_MATCH

Thanks

Comment: This script can't work as written (unless it is itself embedded in double quotes that you haven't shown us) as `$CNEW` will not be evaluated there. Also awk isn't going to like an unquoted string in that assignment. Did you mean `{$CNEW}` or did you mean `${CNEW}`? Are the `{}` literal values to go into the file?

Comment: Sorry I should have said this is being called via php exec()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v s="$CNEW" '/WORD_MATCH/ { n=1; if (s) $0=s; else next; } 1; END { if(s && !n) print s }' file
```

#### How it works

- `-v s="$CNEW"`

  This creates `s` as an awk variable with the value `$CNEW`.  Note that the use of `-v` neatly eliminates the quoting problems that can occur by trying to define `s` in a BEGIN block.
- `/WORD_MATCH/ { n=1; if (s) $0=s; else next; }`

  If the current line matches `WORD_MATCH`, then set `n` to `1`.  If `s` is non-empty, then set the current line to `s`.  If not, skip the rest of the commands and start over on the `next` line.
- `1`

  This is cryptic shorthand for print the line.
- `END { if(s && !n) print s }`

  At the end of the file, if `n` is still not `1` and `s` is non-empty, then print `s`.